Why wont my VS html editor recognise my Kendo code and auto-complete it?
My Visual Studio is having following issues:

Code autocompletion has stopped working.
Code does not highlight with different colors as it used to. It just appears to be plain white text.

Ive Uninstalled and reinstalled, ive tried repairing the installation nothing fixes it.
My VS version is 2019 ver 16.11.37
The image below shows how it looks at present.

How can I make it work like it used to? Any help is appreciated.

What version+edition of VS are you using? Your screenshot doesn't resemble any version of VS I've ever used.

@TusharJadav Reporting on IDE behaviour and syntax-colouring issues is a valid reason for posting a screenshot-of-code.

@Dai im using VS 2019 version 16.11.36

My first suggestion is to use the 2022 version, but if for some reason you prefer to use 2019, and if this issue only occurs in some pages and not in the whole project, maybe sometimes the automatic format in some versions of Visual Studio does not work properly due to syntax errors in ASP .NET Razor codes. In this case, if you cannot find the typographical errors by reviewing the codes, I suggest you add a new ASP .NET Razor page. Copy the codes element by element from the problematic page to the new page. Pay attention to the behavior of Visual Studio in automatic code format. When the format is not done correctly, there is probably a problem in that part of your code and you should check more closely. If that part is extra and it was wrongly placed in the previous codes, delete it. Also, if the format of the whole page is damaged by copying the new element, press Ctrl+Z once to undo it.

Hi, I now believe this issue is caused by some weird internal company security system that's stopping the intellisense from working in this very specific instance. thankfully intellisense works on my personal computer so hopefully it can be solved. thank you for the help

Hi. you're welcome. Glad you found a solution to the problem. I hope it will be completely resolved.
This security reason that you mentioned may have caused this problem. Because when I run Visual Studio on a laptop and in limited login without admin access, some problems occur, for example, it hangs in the initialization for some plugins and extensions and remains waiting.
